# constant sum question results analysis - please help

Tags: t-test, survey, compositional-data

I ran a study with a constant sum question: participants had to divide 100 units (I called the units USD) between 5 possibilities. In other words, they had to bet on five possibilities: 1 object out of 5 has a property vs. 2 objects out of 5 have a property vs. 3 objects out of five have a property vs. 4 objects out of five have a property vs. 5 objects out of 5 have a property.

Next, I ran a paired samples t-test to compare the answers (or 'bets') on two possibilities, namely that 4 objects out of five have a property vs. that 5 objects out of 5 have a. property. A reviewer pointed out that I cannot use a paired-samples t-test because the answers are not independent of one another: your next bets are dependent on the previous ones as it all must sum to 100 (the bet on 5 is dependent on how much you already bet on 4). Which significance test should I use then? Please help!

Comment: Am I right to assume that I should first transform the data to a log ratio and then perform a MANOVA + Hoteling t square test on CoDaPack? reference: https://ddd.uab.cat/pub/sort/sort_a2015m7-12v39n2/sort_a2015m7-12v39n2p231.pdf